# Proper freezing for King Crab Legs

Tags: storage, frozen, crab

A local grocer is selling cooked, frozen King Crab Legs.  I'd like to buy them a week in advance of Christmas and keep them frozen until it's time to eat them.

If they sit in my freezer for 7 days, will that be too much time?  (will they go bad in any way?)  And assuming they aren't fully frozen, do I have to thaw them first before putting them in the freezer?  (like you would for raw meat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep them frozen. Freezing and thawing will impact the texture adversely. Wrap them well.  For 7 days you will not have a problem.  For longer storage, vacuum sealing is better so that you avoid freezer burn.

Answer (score 1):

I remember my parents freezing their seafood in those waxed milk cartons filled with water(?). Turns out that's not far off. A number of resources suggest using a brine (salt water solution) in a sealable freezer bag. 
I imagine tourists must be buying a lot of fish/seafood for them to include [Tips on Freezing Seafood](https://www.tourismpei.com/tips-on-freezing-seafood) on the Prince Edward Islands tourist website.